# Is it safe to store in a field the TaskScheduler of the UI Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

Is it safe to store the TaskScheduler of the UI Thread in a field as following:

```
class TaskSchedulerReference {

    private readonly _uiTaskScheduler; 

    // Constructor is called by the UI Thead 
    public TaskSchedulerReference() {
        _uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    }

    public TaskScheduler UiTaskScheduler { get { return _uiTaskScheduler; } }
}
```

...so that it is possible to notify the UI at any time from any background thread in a `Task.ContinueWith(action, TaskSchedulerReference.UiTaskScheduler)`callback.

Is it guaranteed that the reference remains valid during the whole application life-cycle?

Comment: This static initializer is very dangerous. Please refer to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751465/prism-5-delegatecommandbase-raisecanexecutechanged-throws-invalidoperationexcept/27406194#27406194) where I explain how can such a thing mess up the whole app. It's not guaranteed that this field will be initialized on the UI thread.

Comment: Note that this isn't the SC, it's a `TaskScheduler` that uses the SC.

Comment: Plese forget the static initializer. It is not the point. I correct the question...

Comment: @dymanoid not really dangerous :) - somewhat random, can be called at any particular time from any context, will kill class on failure - but otherwse perfectly safd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from that dubious `// This class is first visited by the UI Thread`, yes. Use an explicit initializer (explicitly run from the UI thread) instead, the JIT is not guaranteed to run the class initializer on the UI thread.

However, I prefer capturing the context as a local variable. Exposing anything as global state is tricky in multi-threading (and asynchronous programming). Always try using as local a state as possible. It also reeks of the old `IsInvokeRequired` pattern. Every method should be very explicit about what happens where - it's very easily to accidentally introduce re-entrant code and deadlocks otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. My fear doesn't relate to the static field (the example was just to provide an illustration): The question is rather : may a reference to the SynchronizationContext become invalid? In particular, I fear calls to `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context)`, that would make the stored field completely out-of-date...

Comment: @jeromerg Yeah, you don't have to fear that in a windows forms application - if you have more than a single synchronization context, you're in trouble anyway :D . If you ever find yourself writing a web application, though, it will not work - that's yet another reason to pass the context rather than having it in a global field somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [code for `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs,a8790c1e6086ae5d) you can see that it creates a `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` by capturing `SynchronizationContext.Current`.

As long as you do that on the UI thread you would capture the UI's SC and  `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context)` can't change your captured context.

Note that what you store is a `TaskScheduler` that holds the SC and not the SC itself. If you want to capture the SC just use `SynchronizationContext.Current`.